# How to handle dynamically changing value with selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium

Below is what HTML has. If I click using below XPATH, it's working fine.  But data-qtip value keep changing and also there are other class with same name as above in HTML.

How can I click on whatever the value that appears `@data-qtip`?

**HTML**:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">    
<span class="item-context-link" data-qtip="3711672330">3711672330</span>    
</a>
```

**Code**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@data-qtip, '3711672330')]").click()
```

Comment: How many data-qtip you see in HTML ? is it possible to share page url ?

Comment: There are 9 data-qtip I see in HTML and I can't share entire HTML because it is exceeding the characters limit.

Comment: Please see my answer below, let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on OP response, there are `9 data-qtip` and due to lack of HTML, I will proide you solution using **xpath indexing.**

```
(//span[@data-qtip])[1]
```

should represent the `first 1 element`, `[2]` should represent the **second element**.

```
(//span[@data-qtip])[2]
```

and so on..

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

You can try to increase the index to have a **unique matching node** in **HTMLDOM**.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//span[@data-qtip])[1]").click()
```

Comment: Indexing worked. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds good. Was it helpful ?if yes, can you accept this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `DOM` if `data-qtip` is unique attribute then you can use below `xPath`

**xPath**:

```
//span[@data-qtip]
```

**Code**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-qtip]").click()
```